# C# - Allowing Method to Abort Asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, abort

I am creating a report generator that allows the user to do two simple things:

1. Start the generation of the report.
2. Abort the generation of the report while in progress.

For unit testing purposes, I have isolated the business logic. The unit test for the abort method contains the following code:

```
reportGenerator.GenerateReport();
reportGenerator.Abort();
```

The abort method simply sets an private field flagging whether an abort has been called:

```
public void Abort()
{
    aborted = true;
}
```

The inside of GenerateReport starts a new thread on which the guts of the report generation execute, checking for an abort flag in several places along the way.

The problem I am encountering is that my unit test is **not even executing** the abort method until **after** GenerateReport() finishes executing, thus the abort flag is only being set after the execution has finished.

I believe that the issue has to do with both GenerateReport() and Abort() being called from within the same thread in the Unit Test. It seems that if I create a new thread in the Unit Test code, and call the GenerateReport() from the new thread, I would be able to asynchronously call the abort method, however it seems messy to have to create a thread outside of all my business logic.

If anyone has any suggestions or answers on the best way to do what I'm trying to do, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to run one or the other in a different thread. The same thread can't interrupt itself! You can either run `GenerateReport()` as a task in a different thread, or you can start a task that will call `Abort()` after some delay. But one way or the other, if you want to test this functionality, you need to have two different threads working on the problem.\

Comment: It could be that the other thread doesn't see the change to the abort variable (or is out of order with something else that is checked--which is more likely on x86).  But, hard to tell with no code that shows the check of the abort variable.  Typically, I'd suggest using CancellationTokenSource instead of a variable like this due to the synchronization issues you must deal with on your own.

Comment: There is a general-purpose pattern for cancellation of tasks which involves `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken`s provided by it. And you probably should use it.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question with:

> I believe that the issue has to do with both GenerateReport() and Abort() being called from within the same thread in the Unit Test.

You can't have a thread abort itself, that doesn't make sense. You could accomplish your task only if you had two threads.

Consider **why you need** this in the first place. If you want a responsive UI during the report generation you would create a new thread in the UI code, definitely not your business logic. You would most likely benefit from a `BackgroundWorker` class.